# Opening two separate Excel workbooks from a third

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to automate something I do each day and I am not getting very far.

We run a report from an HR system each day and then compare the Id's to 
1) a list of Id's we are working on this fortnight
2) a list of Id's we worked on last fortnight
3) the report that came out yesterday - so that any that weren't on the first two lists but were picked up by someone yesterday get marked.

I am writing this code in a separate spreadsheet so that this remains each day and the downloaded spreadsheet gets updated.

I thought this would be easy, but it is a couple of years since I've written much vba. But no matter what I try I can't seem to get it to read the third file.

All files are open already.

So the first file is the macro file, which just allows the other files to be selected.

The second file is the Excel document which comes from the HR system. This has "Empl ID" as the first column from A2 up to around to A500 at times.

The third file is the Excel document which details the ID's we are working on this fortnight and has "Emplid" as the first column.

With the code below I can't get the third Excel doc to work, I just get Run time error 9 : subscript out of range.

If I add a watch for Workbooks(txtMSR) I can see the sheet "MSR" as Item1 in Sheets and the name for that is MSR.

Any assistance would be most welcomed.

````
Dim txtWorkbook As String
Dim vLoop, vLoop2 As Integer
Dim vEID As String
Dim txtMSR As String
Dim txtWork2 As String

'Get workbook name less the .xls bit
'C13 has ps.xls in it

txtWorkbook = Left(Range("C13"), InStr(Range("C13"), ".xls") - 1)

'Next check who has the employees on this MSR
'Set counters to "zero"
vLoop = 2
vLoop2 = 2

'C7 has MSR Fortnight 20190419-20190502.xlsm in it   
txtMSR = Left(Range("C7"), InStr(Range("C7"), ".xlsm") - 1)

Do Until Workbooks(txtWorkbook).Sheets("ps").Range("A" & vLoop).Text = ""
    vPMKeyS = Workbooks(txtWorkbook).Sheets("ps").Range("A" & vLoop).Value
    ```
    'The line below produces the error.  
    ```
    Do Until Workbooks(txtMSR).Sheets("MSR").Range("A" & vLoop2).Text = ""
       If (vPMKeyS = Workbooks(txtMSR).Sheets("ps").Range("A" & vLoop2).Value) Then
            Workbooks(txtWorkbook).Sheets("ps").Range("N1").Text = "Y"
       End If
       vLoop2 = vLoop2 + 1
    Loop
    vLoop = vLoop + 1
Loop
````

Comment: Have you considered getting the data with "Get & Transform", aka Power Query? It is so much easier to work with than VBA.

Comment: There's no need to remove the file extensions from the values in C7/13 - in fact your code will be more robust if you don't do that.

Comment: Don't you need to reset `vLoop2` at some point (for the next iteration of the outer loop)